# Allow user to access specific table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have created a new user called joe, using this SQL statement

```
CREATE USER joe WITH password 'password' NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE;
```

I have table order, product and address, I want joe to only have read access to product table and joe should not be able to execute UPDATE/DELETE sql statement, only SELECT sql statement. I don't want joe to SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE on order and address table, how can I do that? Is it possible for postgresql?

Comment: [Yes.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html)

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I don't want joe to see order and address tables, can I ask you, how to do this part?

Comment: You can't really hide the _existence_ of the tables in Postgres.